# When $\frac{C(n, k)}{n^{k-1}} > 1$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I came across this while considering the *subset sum problem* in relation to another problem. Define the ratio,

$$R(n,k) = \frac{C(n, k)}{n^{k-1}} = \frac{\binom n k}{n^{k-1}}$$

and the integer sequence,

$$s_k = k!+\frac{k(k-1)}{2} = k!+C(k,2)$$

where $C(k,2)$ yield the *triangular numbers*. How do we show that,

$$\begin{aligned}
R\big(n,\,k\big)\; &< 1,\quad\text{if}\;n < s_k\\
R\big(n,\,k\big)\; &\geq 1,\quad\text{if}\;n \geq s_k
\end{aligned}$$

For example, let $k=6$ so $s_6 = 735$, then,

$$\begin{aligned}
R\big(734,\,6\big)\; &= 0.99877\dots\\
R\big(735,\,6\big)\; &= 1.00016\dots
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: This is a very interesting result, can you explain more the context of how this arose?

Comment: @Nitin: I was considering if "equal sums of like powers" can be considered as a _subset sum problem_. In a way it is: if the entries are all powers and if you have a sufficient range, then a subset is bound to sum to zero. However, it is very inefficient, since as $n$ increases then $R(n,k) > 1$. It made me wonder what is the least $n$ such that $R(n,k) < 1$. I was fortunate there seemed to be a closed-form, though I have no proof that holds true for all $k$.

Comment: @Nitin: I simplified the definition of $s_k$, but the question remains the same.

Comment: $\frac{735}{6!} \approx 1.02$

Comment: @Alex: And $\frac{734}{6!} \approx 1.019$. You really should have calculated that as well.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII - if you don't get an answer here, I might suggest asking this on Overflow. Usually they want research level questions, but this seems interesting enough. If you do end up doing so, a link would be appreciated as I too want to see how this resolved.

Comment: Well, for $n=k!+t$ we need to compare $(1+t/k!)\cdot(1-1/(k!+t))(1-2/(k!+t))\ldots(1-(k-1)/(k!+t))$ withs 1. Shouldn't be hard (take logarithm, bound it...) — and at least genesis of $s_k$ is clear.

Comment: @Nitin: Are you satisfied with any of the answers below?

Comment: I hope to read through it and try to understand it thoroughly today, hold on.

Comment: @Nitin I also would be interested in your feedback; it took me a while to work through this argument.

Comment: @user84413 So I accept that this argument shows such a number provides a ratio greater than one, but not that n-1 will have a ratio smaller than 1.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an outline of a solution.  Fix $k$; we seek the unique (possibly non-integral) $n>k$ such that ${n\choose k}=n^{k-1}$.  Expanding the left-hand side, we have
$$ n^k - {k\choose 2}n^{k-1} + {\rm error} = k!\, n^{k-1}$$
If the error term weren't there, this would give $n = k! + {k\choose 2}$.  We'll show that the error is between zero and $n^{k-1}$.

To do this, we have to look more closely at the polynomial

$$n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) = n^k - c_1 n^{k-1} + c_2 n^{k-2} - \cdots$$
where $c_r$ is the sum of the products of all $r$-subsets of $\{0,\ldots,k-1\}$.
It's easy to see that for each $r$, we have
$c_r < k^2 c_{r-1}$; this is because each $(r-1)$-subset can be extended to an $r$-subset
in less than $k$ ways, and each such extension increases the product by less than $k$.

We'll assume $k>6$, so that $k^4<k!<n$. Then $c_r < k^2 c_{r-1} < n c_{r-1}$, so that
$n^k - c_1 n^{k-1} + c_2 n^{k-2} -\cdots$ is an alternating sum of terms whose absolute value decreases.  Thus we have

$$n^k - c_1 n^{k-1} < n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) < n^k - c_1 n^{k-1} + c_2 n^{k-2}$$

We have $c_1={k\choose 2}$ and $c_2< k^2{k\choose2}<k^4 < n$, so we get
$$n^k - c_1 n^{k-1} < n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1) < n^k - c_1 n^{k-1} + n^{k-1},$$
i.e. the "error" is sandwiched between $0$ and $n^{k-1}$ as claimed.

To see that this finishes the argument, recall that we chose $n$ in order that ${n\choose k}=n^{k-1}$.  So $n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)=k!n^{k-1}$, so the "sandwiching" inequality says
$$n^k - c_1 n^{k-1} < k! n^{k-1} < n^k - c_1 n^{k-1} + n^{k-1}.$$
Dividing all 3 sides by $n^{k-1}$, and adding $c_1={k\choose 2}$ to all 3 sides, this gives
$$n < k! + {k\choose2} < n+1,$$
i.e. $s_k-1<n<s_k$.
Observing that ${n\choose k}/n^{k-1}$ is increasing in $n$, for $n>k$, this implies that for $n=s_k-1$ the ratio is less than 1, and for $n=s_k$ the ratio is greater than 1.

This gives the result for $k>6$; smaller values can be checked by hand.

Comment: @user84413: You are the one who offered the bounty. Are you satisfied with the answer?

Comment: I need to look at it more closely to see if I understand everything.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  One thing I wasn't sure about was how Alex's answer shows that the error is positive; I can see that it shows that the error is positive for large enough n, but don't you need it to be true for $n=k!+\binom{k}{2}$?  (It actually seems to always be positive, so I don't think this is a real problem.)

Comment: Fair enough.  I've edited the answer to use an alternating series argument, which I think is cleaner anyway, for which it's clearer where I use Alex's observation that $n>k!$.

Comment: Nice argument, much clearer with the alternating series. But how does this show that C(n-1,k) < (n-1)^(k-1)? It is not obvious to me.

Comment: I added a paragraph at the end to make that more explicit.

Comment: Nice solution, and this edited version is a little easier to follow. (In the next-to-last paragraph, do you mean $s_k$ rather than $c_k$?)

Comment: Right -- fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Well, not an exact answer, unfortunately, but maybe it will help a bit with the intuition. It seems to me you are actually looking at the asymptotic case, $ n \to \infty$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^{k-1}} \sim \frac{n^k}{n^{k-1} k!} = \frac{n}{k!}
$$
because for large $n \ \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} \sim n^k$. Then clearly the ratio is greater than 1 for $n>k!$.

Comment: No, not asymptotics. Sure we can get the ratio $R(n,k)>1$ if we choose large enough $n$, but that's no challenge. We are looking for the very **first** value $s_k$ such that the ratio turns from $<1$, to $>1$.